# Machine Cycles for the DJNZ instruction in 8051? 2 or 3?

Tags: assembly, 8051

So the opcodes sheet provided by our instructor and also some searches online tells me that the DJNZ instruction takes 2/3 machines cycles to execute. Can someone tell me exactly when it takes 2 and when it takes 3 machine cycles? Example codes would be really helpful too!!

Comment: I would assume 2 if no jump and 3 if jump, but would have to google it.

Comment: I guess it may depend on your chip, but those that I know all do it in 2 clocks.

Comment: I looked at different opcode sheets too! My confusion is with two different machine cycles being listed in all the cases. I guess it depends on whether it jumps or not!

Comment: I can't find any reference that gives 2 values.

Comment: You might have found references to the Zilog Z80 that has the same instruction and takes a different amount of cycles depending on whether the jump is taken or not. For the 8051, I don't know any references that say "3".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DJNZ always takes 2 machine cycles